# ArrayList Throws Error When Error Says Length is Longer

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

For some background info, I'm making a shop system, whereas coins collected are stored in an array, and then removed when buying an item.

The problem is, this error is thrown even when the amount of coins is greater than the price (i.e., 80 coins, but only subtracting 75 from the ArrayList).

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOfBoundsException: length=202; index=-1;
```

The code loop giving me a hard time (I have a few others like this, and the problem always seems to be when only a few coins are left):

```
if(this.name.equals("SHOTGUN BURST") && gamescreen.map.getCoinSize() >= this.price) {
player.isShotty = true;
for(int f = 0; f < this.price; f++) { 
       gamescreen.map.coinsCollect.remove(gamescreen.map.getCoinSize() - 1 - f);
   }
}
```

Comment: `gamescreen.map.getCoinSize() - 1 - f` evaluates to `-1`. You cannot have  negative index.

Comment: If f = 0?  The -1 is because the array starts with 0, so the max number isn't the actual size of the array.  And the f is to point to the index I want to remove (starting from the last one).

Comment: Are you sure your getCoinSize() is returning the correct value? For example if there are coins collected `(0, 1, 2, 3)`, the size must be 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array index of `-1` (what the stacktrace says you're trying to access) is ALWAYS out of bounds.

For debugging purposes, temporarily change your code to this:

```
for(int f = 0; f < this.price; f++) {
   System.out.println("f = %d", f);
   System.out.println("getCoinSize() = %d", gamescreen.map.getCoinSize());
   System.out.println("Array Index = %d", (gamescreen.map.getCoinSize()-1-f); 
   gamescreen.map.coinsCollect.remove(gamescreen.map.getCoinSize()-1-f);
}
```

Don't say "for some reason X is happening".  Use some sort of debugging approach.  Alternative to output statements would be using a breakpoint and stepping through your program line by line.

Comment: Is this an answer to his problem?

Comment: For whatever reason subtracting 1 from my original coin size is giving me an output counting down by twos (i.e., I have 155 coins, 154 - 1, 154 - 2...is somehow giving me 153, 151, 149...).

Comment: I got it.  Since I can't answer my own question yet, I will say that it basically came down to storing the initial amount of coins I had, so the for loop didn't take into account the ones I already removed when searching the indeces.  But basically, "An array index of -1 is ALWAYS out of bounds"!

Comment: int j = gamescreen.map.coinsCollect.size();
   for(int f = 0; f < this.price; f++) {
    if(f == 0) {
    gamescreen.map.coinsCollect.remove(j - 1);
    }
    else {
     gamescreen.map.coinsCollect.remove(j - f - 1);
    }
   }

Comment: If `f==0`, isn't `(j-1)` the same as `(j-f-1)`?

Comment: Oh yeah, I was in a rush so I absentmindedly put that if statement as a safeguard.  Thanks again!